# TextField and Label Array

Tags: arrays, javafx

Here I'm trying to create `TextField` and `Label` in arrays and add them to a `GridPane` but getting problem in commented line and onwards.

```
GridPane pane=new GridPane();
pane.setPadding(new Insets(50,0,0,50));
pane.setVgap(20);
pane.setHgap(40);
Label Arrival= new Label("Arrival Time");
Label Burst= new Label("Burst Time");
TextField[] ArrvialInput= new TextField[10];
TextField[] BurstInput= new TextField[10];
Label Process= new Label();
for (int i=0; i<=10-1; i++) {
    TextField textFieldA = new TextField();
    TextField textFieldB = new TextField();
    ArrvialInput[i] = textFieldA;
    BurstInput[i] = textFieldB;
    Process= new Label("P"+(i+1));
}
for (int i=0; i<=10-1; i++) {
    pane.add(Process, 0, i+1); //Run Time error here 
    pane.add(Arrival, 1, i+1);
    pane.add(ArrvialInput[i], 2, i+1);
    pane.add(Burst, 0, i);
    pane.add(BurstInput[i], 4, i+1);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the compiler showing an error and not a runtime error being thrown? (If you've got a compile time error even after fixing the issue commented lines and 3 other lines in the second loop will throw a runtime error, since you're adding the same node to the same parent multiple times.) What's the error message? Furthermore do you import javafx `javafx.scene.control.Label` and `javafx.scene.control.TextField` or the awt classes of the same name?

Comment: Yes I've imported `javafx.scene.control.Label` and `javafx.scene.control.TextField` and yes you're right I'm getting Run time Error in commented line

Comment: Adding the same node to the same parent multiple times results in an exception (adding it to a second parents will remove the node from the old parent). The second iteration of the second loop tries to add the `Process` label for the second time resulting in an exception. I don't see a point in using 2 different loops for creating the nodes and adding them to the `GridPane`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this if you don't need to access the labels but @fabian is correct in saying "Adding the same node to the same parent multiple times results in an exception"

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        GridPane pane=new GridPane();
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(50,0,0,50));
        pane.setVgap(20);
        pane.setHgap(40);
//        Label Arrival= new Label("Arrival Time");
//        Label Burst= new Label("Burst Time");
        TextField[] ArrvialInput= new TextField[10];
        TextField[] BurstInput= new TextField[10];
//        Label Process= new Label();
        for (int i=0; i<=10-1; i++) {
            TextField textFieldA = new TextField();
            TextField textFieldB = new TextField();
            ArrvialInput[i] = textFieldA;
            BurstInput[i] = textFieldB;
//            Process= new Label("P"+(i+1));
        }
        for (int i=0; i<=10-1; i++) {
            pane.add(new Label("P"+(i+1)), 0, i+1);
            pane.add(new Label("Arrival Time"), 1, i+1);
            pane.add(ArrvialInput[i], 2, i+1);
            pane.add(new Label("Burst Time"), 3, i+1);
            pane.add(BurstInput[i], 4, i+1);
        }


        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```